# Shield enemies tactic

Tags: hellblade-senuas-sacrifice

I am quiet good at the combat in hellblade, generally not dying and most often than not getting no damage. <\Trumpet blown> However, the shield enemies are giving me trouble. The only reliable tactic I have used on them is to dodge then until I can enter focus mode and then hit them with heavy attacks combos.

*Is there a simpler way?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finished the game a while ago so I'm not completely sure, but IIRC:

- they do a heavy attack which you can dodge to the side of the weapon, this allows you to hit them (but usually just once)
- parrying might also work, but I'm not 100% anymore
- the best method is to use the unarmed attack to beat the shield aside and then attack them with your sword

Comment: Dodge and hit is what I used but it is tedious. You can parry the mace attacks, not the shield ones. The later would be a good indication as to why we have unarmed attacks!